# Application re-consuming the entire Kafka topic upon restart

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, reactor

I'm using Kafka Reactor for Spring. When we restart the application (same group-id, etc...) using `auto.offset.reset = latest` the application will restart re-consuming a lot of messages. I am not even entirely sure that it is from the beginning, but surely it is a lot of them.

Why does this happen? I thought the offset reset to latest would avoid this. Also my understanding is that the setting only applies when the offsets are lost. Another option is that the application never really commits? This is the consumer config:

```
allow.auto.create.topics = true
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.offset.reset = latest
    bootstrap.servers = [xxx]
    check.crcs = true
    client.dns.lookup = default
    client.id = 
    client.rack = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    enable.auto.commit = false
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    group.id = pdp-fragments-group
    group.instance.id = null
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.leave.group.on.close = true
    isolation.level = read_uncommitted
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
    max.poll.records = 500
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = SSL
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    session.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.key.password = [hidden]
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = xxx
    ssl.keystore.password = [hidden]
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = config/kafkakeys/KafkaCaCerts.jks
    ssl.truststore.password = [hidden]
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

code:

```
 public Flux<ReceiverRecord<String, String>> makeReceiverFlux() {
        var receiverOptions = ReceiverOptions.<String, String>create(consumerProps)
                .subscription(Collections.singletonList(topic));
        var kafkaReceiver = KafkaReceiver.create(receiverOptions);
        return Flux.defer(kafkaReceiver::receive);
    }

    public Flux<ReceiverRecord<String, String>> transformAndCommitKafkaMessages(Flux<ReceiverRecord<String, String>> kafkaFlux,
                                                                                RecordsProcessor recordProcessor) {
        return parallelise(kafkaFlux, recordProcessor);

    }

   

    Flux<ReceiverRecord<String, String>> parallelise(Flux<ReceiverRecord<String, String>> kafkaFlux,
                                                     RecordsProcessor recordsProcessor) {
        return kafkaFlux.groupBy(msg -> msg.partition() % nWorkers)
                .flatMap(groupedFlux -> groupedFlux.publishOn(this.scheduler)
                        .flatMap(record -> measureTime(process(recordsProcessor, record)))
                        .sample(Duration.ofSeconds(commitIntervalSeconds))
                        .concatMap(record -> commitRecord(record)));
    }
```

Comment: can you share a consumer code?

Comment: When data is being produced to the topic while you consumer is down, and then restarting it will have the consumer read all those messages. The auto.offset.reset configuration will not have any impact as you are not changing your consumer group and also you are committing the consumed messages.

Comment: this happens after a simple deploy... yeah I agree the offset reset should not be involved. The only explanation is that it's not committing to me

Comment: Before you start the application, please check the commit offset of your consumer and the latest offset of that topic. It would give you an idea about the number of messages your consumer group may consume. Please note that the `auto.offset.reset` config kicks in if your consumer group does not have a valid offset committed.